# Windows 11 displays a pop-up telling me I can turn on HDR - but then tells me that it's not supported

Tags: display, windows-11, hdr

Every time I plug my Dell XPS 13 (9360) laptop into my [Dell U2720Q monitor](https://www.dell.com/en-lt/work/shop/cty/pdp/spd/dell-u2720q-monitor), I get the following popup on Windows 11:

> **HDR-ready display detected** 
> Good news-you can turn on HDR in display

When I click on it I'm taken into **System > Display**. If I then click on "HDR", I'm told that both "HDR video streaming" and "Use HDR" on "Display 1: DELL U2720Q" are "Not supported".

I have the latest Dell U2720Q (TypeC4K2K60HDR) driver (version 1.1.0.0, dated 24-Mar-2022) installed on Windows 11 (22H2, build 22621.819).

**How can I enable HDR?**

Comment: DisplayPort or HDMI? What GPU do you have? What versions of DisplayPort and HDMI does it support? What versions of HDMI or DisplayPort does the cable support?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm connected to the monitor with USB-C. Laptop GPU is Intel 620.

Comment: I suspect your hardware does not support HDR. I assume connecting to the monitor over DisplayPort isn't an option?

Comment: @Ramhound Possibly, although I did like the convenience of having one cable to connect up the display and all peripherals!

Comment: When you attempt that as a solution, to rule out a cable bandwidth problem, [edit] your question.